# How can I get the current state of my div animation?

Tags: html, css, safari, styling

I am using Safari, thus to make it easier to answer my question I will just use the `-webkit-` prefix on my animations.

I am making a menu that is in the corner. When the user hovers, it spans the entire website until the user leaves the menu, then it recedes again.

The only problem I have is that if the user doesn't wait until the menu bar is completely spanning the webpage, then the bar flickers to get to its position in the animation. What can I do to fix this and make the animation start from the current width of the `div`? Here is my `CSS`:

```
#menubar {
    /* Menu bar styling */
}

#menubar:hover {
    -webkit-animation: openMenu 2s;
    width: 100%;
}

#menubar:not(:hover) {
    -webkit-animation: closeMenu 2s;
    width: 75px;
}

/* Animations */

@-webkit-keyframes openMenu {
    from {width:75px;}
    to {width:100%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes closeMenu {
    from {width:100%;} /* How do I get the current width of the div here instead of using width:100%;? */
    to {width:75px;}
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need keyframes? You could achieve the same result using transitions, like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7L4nwpt/2/).

```
#menubar {
    /* Menu bar styling */
    width: 75px;

    transition: width 2s;
}

#menubar:hover {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Basically, you tell that the menubar should be at 100% when hovered, at 75px when idle, and the width transition should last 2s and everything works.

Comment: Wow. That is a way better option! Thanks so much for the tip.